# Tracking Push Notifications?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

What kind of tracking measures are available for Mobile Push?

- Can you track opens/engagement?
- Can you measure how many sales were generated from a push notification?

Comment: have you gone through [Salesforce Mobile Push Notifications Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_overview.htm), I think you might find your answers there.

Comment: More info at [MobilePush and Journey Builder for Apps SDKs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/mobile-push-sdk.htm) ---> "The message wizard and preview features make it simple to create, deliver, and track push notifications"

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Push tracks two main analytics that can be used to infer engagement.
We do track Opens (http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobilepush/analytics/opens/) and we also track time in application.

To your second point, we don't have a current solution in-house that would tell you about a sale coming directly from a push notification. You could however take Open times and compare them to sale times etc to try and get the information you are looking for.

Comment: A bit more documentation: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobilepush/analytics/account_app_and_list_statistics/

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping their was an equivalent to UTMs for push notifications. Looks like this will have to be a custom tracking solution to be built into the app.

Comment: Is there a system table where interactions with the notifications are held?